# Unix command used through Make file

Tags: xcode, macos

i want to know if i create a make file of xcode application then we used UNIX command through application on real device.Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the question - could you please elaborate?

Comment: i want to know that how i used UNIX command on my Xcode Application

Comment: Is your question related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476231/compile-the-entire-bash-shell-into-my-app ? If so, my interpretation is that you would like to run bash commands on an iPhone but don't know how. Is that true?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't tag your question appropriately: it has more to do with Apple's Xcode than with   Makefiles.  You're only going to confuse Unix programmers if you don't identify it as related to Mac OS X.  Do yourself a favor and retag it by adding tags like macosx and xcode; I can't do it myself as I don't have enough rep.

As for the question itself, of course you can write a Makefile that would build an Xcode project from the command line; it's only a matter of emulating the step what Xcode does itself.  The actual steps really depend on your project, so you would have to tell us a bit more about it, and have a look at [Apple's docs](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/A_Tour_of_Xcode/000-Introduction/qt_intro.html).

Answer (score 0):

It's very unclear what you're asking.  It seems that you want to execute a shell command through your application.  If so, make is irrelevant, unless it's make that you're trying to run through your application.

Anyway.  Most languages have a standard library call named "system" which executes commands as thought they were typed into a shell.  You can also get the return code of the application to see if it ran successfully.  There are variations which allow you to set the input and output files (to pipe I/O out or back into your application directly).

Comment: Yes i used System which executes command successfully on simulator but not on real device

Comment: System is the proper way.  If you have some device that this isn't working on, that may be a security feature or simply a limitation of the device.  In that case, you'll need to find another solution.

The first step would be to tell us what device you're talking about ;)

Answer (score 0):

Mitali, your reference to "the simulator" above seems to confirm mouviciel's suspicion that you want to run a bash command from within an iPhone application. If that's true, then look at some of the suggested links and maybe try giving some more detail about exactly what it is that you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If the question is actually "I have an iPhone app and I want it to execute Unix commands at runtime when running on the device," the answer is no, you can't.  The Unix shell and shell commands are not present on the device; they're available in the Simulator because simulated apps are actually Mac OS X apps and have access to many features of the development machine that are not present in the device.